Vulnerabilities in Istio-proxy container apt packages (openssl, perl-base, curl) in Azure AKS pod
I'm currently managing an application deployed on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) using Istio for service mesh. Recently, while conducting a security audit, I discovered potential vulnerabilities related to apt packages within the Istio-proxy container running in my AKS pods.
Here are the details of my setup:
Istio version: 1.21.2

AKS cluster managed through Azure portal
Istio setup integrated with AKS using Helm charts
Upon inspecting the Istio-proxy container, I found outdated versions of some apt packages that have known vulnerabilities.

For example,
OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 - need to update this package to version greater than 3.0.12.
I have a few questions regarding this issue:

Vulnerability Mitigation: What are the recommended steps to mitigate these vulnerabilities without compromising the stability of Istio or AKS?

Patch Management: How can I effectively manage package updates within Istio-proxy containers running on AKS pods?

Are there any best practices or tools specifically recommended for
this task?

Future Prevention: To prevent similar issues in the future, what strategies should I adopt during the initial setup and ongoing maintenance of Istio on AKS?


I've already reviewed the Istio and AKS documentation, but specific guidance on handling apt package vulnerabilities within Istio-proxy containers in the context of Azure AKS would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance
